# How can I point a domain to multiple ports based on the directory I am browsing to?

Tags: networking, apache2, dns, virtualhost, redirect

I have a server running at home. This server is running on a public IP which is defined on my domain as an A record.

Everything is working currently.

I run Apache for a small website along with Confluence.

```
Apache: 80  
Confluence: 8090
```

What I want to know is how can I set this up so if I browse to:

`domain.net/confluence`

Will Apache know that it should redirect this to port `8090`? Is this simply handled through setting up a virtual host for the same IP but pointing it to that directory and having it listen on `8090`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out I can do this with nginx, which I had planned on setting up anyway.

This is what I did!

Added this under `nginx/sites-available`

```
    server {
    listen www.thelavender.net:80;
    server_name www.thelavender.net;
    location /confluence {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8090/confluence;
    }
}
```

copied this to `nginx/sites-enabled`

in my `conf/server.xml` for Confluence I added the following:

```
proxyName="www.xxxxxxx.net" proxyPort="80" />
```

to the end of the following block of code:

```
<Connector port="8090" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
            maxThreads="48" minSpareThreads="10"
            enableLookups="false" acceptCount="10" debug="0" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
            protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
```

Restarted both Confluence and Nginx and BOOM!!!  Nginx is forwarding port 8090 to 80 and I no longer have to use the ugly URL with the port!!

SWEET!

**UPDATE**

I wanted to come back and update this as I found a better way to setup my server blocks for multiple applications running under the same domain. In my case, I wanted to run Confluence and JIRA behind the same domain.

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm;

server_name www.example.com;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location /jira/ {
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:8080;
   }

location /confluence/ {
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
   client_max_body_size 10M;
}
}
```

Or even simpler

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name www.example.com;

location /confluence {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8090/confluence;
}

location /jira {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/jira;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
}
}
```

Turdah!!!!